# _ = func (assignment to function) in go

Tags: go, cockroachdb

What does this code snippet do?

```
func funcName(para int){}
_ = funcName
```

first line define a function, but what does the second line?

I know many situations in which underscore assign to object, what about a function?

Here is an example from the etcd GitHub repository: [link](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/blob/8e6b81b59abd02b6e86c7cc3d6a22d48a10a3b79/pkg/kv/kvserver/replicate_queue.go#L863)

Comment: The statement does not affect the Go program. I am guessing that the statement was added to the cockroach code to provide a code navigation link for the preceding comment.

Comment: In Go functions are _first class_, so you can assign them to variables and pass them as function parameters. Then `_ = funcName` becomes an assignment like any other. This is valid and would call the function: `foo = funcName; foo(42);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per codes of change commit [`move quorum safeguard into execChangeReplicasTxn`](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pull/56735/commits/51785591b469d590861536737009e2145726eb21) of `_ = execChangeReplicasTxn`

[image]

The removing codes of the left side are moving to function [`execChangeReplicasTxn`](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/blob/master/pkg/kv/kvserver/replica_command.go#L2370), and per the comment

```
NB: the replication layer ensures that the below operations don't cause unavailability
```

It provides a code navigation link to [`execChangeReplicasTxn`](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/blob/master/pkg/kv/kvserver/replica_command.go#L2243) as part of comment.